# How to run ad hoc docker compose commands in Ansible?

Tags: docker-compose, phoenix-framework, ansible-2.x

I have to run several `docker-compose run` commands for my Phoenix web app project. From the terminal I have to run this:

`$ sudo docker-compose run web mix do deps.get, compile`

`$ sudo docker-compose run web mix ecto.create`

`$ sudo docker-compose run web mix ecto.migrate`

While this works fine, I would like to automate it using Ansible. I'm well aware there is the **docker_service** Ansible module that consumes the docker-compose API and I'm also aware of the `definition` option that makes it easy to covert integrate the configuration inside docker-compose.yml into my playbook. 
What I don't know is how do I ensure that the commands above will be run before starting the containers. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar situation like yours, finding no way to run *docker-compose run* commands via *docker* dedicated modules for Ansible. However I ended using [Ansible's *shell* module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html) with success for my purposes. Here we have some examples, adapted for your situation.

### One by one, explicit way

```
- name: Run mix deps.get and compile
  shell: docker-compose run web mix do deps.get, compile
  args:
    chdir: /path/to/directory/having/your/docker-compose.yml
  become: True # because you're using sudo

- name: Run mix ecto.create
  shell: docker-compose run web mix ecto.create
  args:
    chdir: /path/to/directory/having/your/docker-compose.yml
  become: True

- name: Run mix ecto.migrate
  shell: docker-compose run web mix ecto.migrate
  args:
    chdir: /path/to/directory/having/your/docker-compose.yml
  become: True
```

### Equivalent way, but shorter

```
- name: Run mix commands
  shell: docker-compose run web mix "{{ item }}"
  args:
    chdir: /path/to/directory/having/your/docker-compose.yml
  loop:
    - "do deps.get, compile"
    - "ecto.create"
    - "ecto.migrate"
  become: True
```

To run those commands before starting the other containers defined in the `docker-compose.yml` file, maybe a combination of these points can help:

- Use docker volumes to persist the results of getting dependencies, compilation and *Ecto* commands
- Use the `depends_on` configuration option inside the `docker-compose.yml` file
- Use the `service` parameter of [Ansible's *docker_service* module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_service_module.html) in your playbook to run only a subset of containers
- Use disposable containers with your `docker-compose run` commands, via the `--rm` option and possibly with the `--no-deps` option
- In your playbook, execute your `docker-compose run` commands before the `docker_service` task

Some notes:

- I'm using Ansible 2.5 at the moment of writing this answer.
- I'm assuming that *docker-compose* binary is already installed, it's working fine and it's available on the standard system `PATH` on the managed host.
- The `docker-compose.yml` file already exists and has the path *`/path/to/directory/having/your/docker-compose.yml`*, as used in the examples. A variable for that file path could also be used.

That's it!